# Get result for search if some characters were incorrect in android with postgresql

Tags: android, postgresql, search

I want to get result from database if user type some incorrect word, For example the "Ahmed" is stored in database and user types "Ahmad", I want, user get result with "Ahmed". If I use "Like", user must type the exact spell "Ahmed" and if he/she type "Ahmad" the result will be null!

Comment: use the TextWatcher for this purpose

Comment: You need to use postgres "Full text search" or just "pg_trgm" for that.Google for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pg_trgm extension. Install it for your database using the query:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
```

For this table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (t varchar);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Ahmad');
```

You can get this results:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE 'Ahmed' % t;
   t   
-------
 Ahmad
(1 row)

SELECT * FROM test WHERE t LIKE 'Ahmed';
 t 
---
(0 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement this idea I use following code:

```
private final TextWatcher mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (count > 2) {
            //call your async class through which you can make request for get suggestions.
        }
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (count > 2) {
            //call your async class through which you can make request for get suggestions.
        }
    }
};
```